# CS50 Tideman "prints winner of election when some pairs are tied" fails

Tags: c, cs50

Edit:
Fixed! Had to set a value for `(winscore winscores[11];)`, the rest of the code was fine, but could be a bit cleaner. The final condition is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (winscores[10].score >= winscores[i].score)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[winscores[i].candidate]);        
        } 
    }
```

Now all checks are passed!

---

I'm working on CS50 Tideman, but my code doesn't pass the final check: "print_winner prints winner of election when some pairs are tied".

The winner should have the most `false` in the locked matrix, so I count the maximum amount of `false`, then order in descending amount of `false`. Then I print the candidate with the most amount of `false`. Then I check if there's more candidates with that same amount of `false`. If there are any, I print those too. That should print the winner, or winners if multiple candidates have the same amount of `false`... at least I thought, but it still doesn't pass the final check. I'm not sure what's wrong in my code, so any help would be appreciated!

```c
typedef struct {
  int candidate;
  int score;
} winscore;

winscore winscores[11];

// Print the winner of the election
void print_winner(void) {
  // int maxscore = 0;
  // int maxscore[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

  for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++) {
      if (locked[i][j] == false) {
        winscores[i].candidate = i;
        winscores[i].score++;
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++) {
      if (winscores[i].score < winscores[j].score) {
        winscores[10].candidate = winscores[i].candidate;
        winscores[10].score = winscores[i].score;

        winscores[i].candidate = winscores[j].candidate;
        winscores[i].score = winscores[j].score;

        winscores[j].candidate = winscores[10].candidate;
        winscores[j].score = winscores[10].score;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("%s\n", candidates[winscores[0].candidate]);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (winscores[0].score == winscores[i].score) {
      printf("%s\n", candidates[winscores[i].candidate]);
    }
  }

  return;
}
```

Comment: Note: `winscores[i].candidate = winscores[j].candidate; winscores[i].score = winscores[j].score;` could be simplified with `winscores[i] = winscores[j];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least this problem: `winscores[i]` lacks initialization leading to trouble with `winscores[i].score++;`.

```
// winscore winscores[11];
winscore winscores[11] = { 0 };
```